# Is there a solution for R giving an error message "error in loadnamespace" when installing a package?

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I attempt to open up the Tidyverse library after installing the package, the following error messages comes:

```
>library(tidyverse)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘colorspace’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

I also tried to install the package color space using

```
install.packages("colorspace")
```

Exact same error messages shows as above. Please help!

p.sp. I installed Rtools40.

Comment: Install the `colorspace` package.

Comment: I did and still shows the same error message.

Comment: It says "`there is no package called ‘colorspace’`"? That wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Exactly. I am completely lost.

Comment: It sounds like there are warnings/errors that we aren't seeing here. Try this: (1) Restart R, completely, clean start, no `.Rdata` or `.Rproj` files at all. Clean start, where `ls()` is empty and `sessionInfo()` looks sparse. (2) `install.packages("colorspace")`. This should have no errors, and should finish with zero `Warning:`s, just *"successfully unpacked" and *"downloaded binary packages are in..."*, nothing in between. (3) `library(tidyverse)` should now load cleanly (assuming that that is the only issue).

Comment: If the above does not fix it, please post the output from the `sessioninfo`, `install.packages`, and `library` steps. All text, including warnings, errors, and the boring stuff in between. Sometimes it seems meaningless but provides just enough insight to other happenings. Good luck! (I know it stinks to have to restart R, sorry, sometimes dealing with packages that have compiled-code shared libraries can require restarting R.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `install.packages("scales")`.
You can also check for the newest version using the  update button in Rstudio.